# TinyMCE4 - Issue with Parsing HTML Text

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

> These are valid HTML which is not working in TinyMCE4 as per our expectation

```html
<p><span style='text-decoration: line-through'>Test</span></p>

<span style="text-decoration: line-through;"><p>Test</p></span>
```

Here is the link of my [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Pmgaab) . First HTML element is working fine but in second one strikethrough is not coming. Unable to undersatnd the reason.

Any lead or help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please note that your second example is not actually valid HTML.  A `span` tag outside of a `p` tag is not valid HTML.  If you run that code through an HTML validator it will show that the second example is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span style="text-decoration: line-through;"><p>Test</p></span>
```

1) You have put the block level element(p) inside inline element(span), which is wrong by [css specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

2) You haven't added test rule for span[style], that's why it will fail test and remove that before rendering.
[updated fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Pmgaab/1)

Comment: `<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">Test</span>` 

You have removed p tag. But I want to make it work like

`<span style="text-decoration: line-through;"><p>Test</p></span>`

If you will parse in any HTML editor strike through should come.

Comment: Can I ask why ?

Comment: There are lots of p tags & other things. I want to put strike through to whole text by concatination span tag with style at begining

Comment: You can use div instead span, for wrapping. It will valid html. [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Pmgaab/2)

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with TinyMCE before, but it appears that a `<p>` element won't inherit style from a surrounding `<span>`.

Another thing, the `valid_elements` for the second textarea is different from the first. I'd guess that `valid_elements` for the second textarea would need `p[style]` added to allow a styled paragraph.

Comment: U can check my fiddle link. Its not working after changing it also. 

[Fiddle LInk](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Pmgaab)

Answer (score 1):

Your second HTML example is invalid HTML - a `span` is an inline element and cannot wrap a block element like a `p` tag.  If you look at the HTML in the second instance its actually been reduced to:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

Your valid elements still need to be valid HTML.

Comment: If you will check in any HTML Editor both way is working. What is the solution if I want to make it work  like second way i.e span should be surrounded by p tag

Comment: TinyMCE will work to make your content valid HTML - as your second example is invalid TinyMCE won't allow you to use that HTML.  Browsers work very hard to still render invalid HTML so while a browser may render it correctly that does not make it valid/proper HTML.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you very much :)